# Can't use grok to match optional fields

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to parse a firewall log line, however logs don't have the same format.

Then I'm trying to use optional fields like this:

`^.*\[.*(?:app_category:"%{ENCAPSULATED_WORD:app_category}")?.*\];$`

Where ENCAPSULATED_WORD is:

`ENCAPSULATED_WORD (\w{1,}| |\/)*`

But I'm getting the app_category field as null, no matter what I change.

Here's the log line:

`2018-12-14T13:12:25Z Firewall-Logs Firewall  - [action:"Allow"; flags:"XXXXX"; ifdir:"ifdir1"; ifname:"ifname2"; loguid:"{#########}"; origin:"127.0.0.1"; time:"1544793145"; version:"1"; __policy_id_tag:"product=fW"; app_category:"Business / Economy"; app_desc:"Some app"; app_id:"60517565"; app_properties:"Business / Economy, SSL Protocol, Very Low Risk, Business Applications"; app_risk:"1"; app_rule_id:"#id1"; app_sig_id:"60517565:1"; appi_name:"Someapp"; dst:"127.0.0.1"; matched_category:"Business / Economy"; origin_sic_name:"Firewall"; product:"Firewall Control"; proto:"6"; proxy_src_ip:"127.0.0.1"; s_port:"54955"; service:"80"; snid:"8bca47a7"; src:"127.0.0.1"; src_machine_name:"machine.domain.com"; ];`

Comment: For key-value logs like this one, you might be better with the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html)

Comment: The issue is with your regex and I didn't how to solve the issue. Perhaps ask another question, focusing only on the regex part?  In that case, perhaps simplifying the regex to `^.*\[.*?(?:k2:"(?<v2>(\w{1,}| )*)").*\];$` and the log to `[k1:"v1"; k2:"v2 "; k3:"v3";];` might be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you baudsp, I decided to use the kv filter and drop fields that I don't want.

Here's the filter I did:


`kv {
        value_split => ":"
        field_split_pattern => "; "
        source => "brackets_content"
  }`

Comment: One thing that could be used to remove unwanted fields is to use the kv [target option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-target) so that all key-value pair are children of one particular filed (let's say `kv`), then use the [mutate/copy option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-copy) to copy the desired field elsewhere then use the `remove_field` option to remove the `kv` field with the other key-value pairs.